# What is a SHA1_Compress() function?

Tags: sha-1, scrypt

I'm trying to implement the [scrypt](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf) key derivation function using JavaScript. When implementing the algorithm, I found that there was a function called SHA1_Compress listed in the [specification](https://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf). Is the function identical to a normal SHA-1 hash function? Or it is a totally different thing? I tried to search the term with Google but found nothing.

[image: scrypt specification]

Comment: By the way, you know the algorithm you quoted is not scrypt, right?  It's another key derivation called HEKS, an early attempt in the late '90s to make a memory-hard algorithm which apparently nobody ever used.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Oops, actually I haven't finished reading the paper. And implementing the wrong algorithm...

Comment: You might find it easier to start from the RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7914  It should be more or less self-contained, and includes test vectors for the whole algorithm and the various subroutines.

Answer (score 3):

The function SHA-1 is defined on a message $m$ that is a sequence of bits.  It works as follows—this form is named Merkle–Damgård after the people who suggested it in days of yore:

1. Let $m' = m \mathbin\| 1 \mathbin\| 0^p \mathbin\| \operatorname{length}(m)$ be the result of padding $m$ with a one bit, $p$ zero bits, and a 64-bit message length, so that the length of $m'$ is an integral multiple of 512 bits.
2. Break $m'$ into 512-bit blocks $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_n$.
3. Compute $f(\cdots f(f(\mathit{iv}, m_1), m_2)\cdots, m_n)$.

Here $f\colon \{0,1\}^{160} \times \{0,1\}^{512} \to \{0,1\}^{160}$ is the **compression function** which compresses a 160-bit starting state and a 512-bit block into a 160-bit subsequent state, and $\mathit{iv}$ is the standard initialization vector.

In the case of SHA-1, the compression function is $f(h, m) := E_m(h) + h$ where $E_k$ is the SHACAL-1 block cipher—building $f$ out of a block cipher this way is called the Davies–Meyer construction.

**The procedure `SHA1_Compress` computes $f$, the compression function that SHA-1 is built out of.**  Since the $w_i$ are initialized as an output of SHA-1 itself, another way to look at the procedure described here is as an incremental computation of SHA-1—you might use a typical init/update/finalize style of API for this—which periodically treats the current state as a hash itself, which works because SHA-1 has no output filter.